# Can you transfer one Android app to another and "merge" them?

Tags: android, google-play

I have an application called App A with 5000 users and an application called App B with 500 users, each with separate keystores.

Like when a company acquires an app, I'd like to basically merge the two apps under App B, without losing any users from App A.

Ideally, when users update App A they will be transferred over to App B.

Is there any solution for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I dont think so..but lets wait for others

Comment: Both applications are same(code) with different keystores? If yes then yes, otherwise if  the applications are not same(code), then no.

Comment: Different codes-- Does this mean my only option is to give up one of the apps and just encourage users to download the other?